# Finding XML file path in hibernate project

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, file-io

I am working on an hibernate project in which I need to read an xml. I placed those xmls in the same folder as the servlet from which I am trying to access those xmls. Now I don't know what is the correct path to access those xmls. Here is my project file structure. As  can see, xmls are placed in com.strategycreator folder. [image: Project tree structure]

I can't place the xmls in a public directory as they need to be in a secure location.

Answer (score 0):

If you need these files to be inaccessible to web page requests, you need to put them in your classpath and use them as resources.

The easiest way to find out the path to use for a classpath resource, is to generate the WAR, look inside the WAR in the appropriate JAR and see what path it ended up having and use that.  If the file is "next to" a the class that needs to load it, you can use a relative path, otherwise you need to use the full "/com/strategycreator/groups.xml" path.

Comment: Can u give me a code example of using the full path. I tried doing it but its trying to find it in D:\Softwares\eclipse\com\strategycreator\groups.xml where my eclipse is located.